# Download current html as .html document page using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am needing to export a current html page as a .html file. However, part of it is modified using jQuery. When I use the following code, it exports, but only exports the html that was originally loaded, not the modifications from jQuery.

I am new to javascript & jQuery, so bear with me please!

```js
$('#modify').keyup(function() {
         var val = $(this).val();
         $('#text_to_mofify').html(val);
        });
        var a = $("#test");
        a.download = "export.html";
        a.href = "data:text/html," + $('#main').html();
        a.innerHTML = "Export content";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
        <p id="text_to_modify">Hello World</p>
    </div>
    
    <input type="text" id="modify" />
    <a id="test"></a>
```

The above snippet will export the html with a `P` tag containing Hello World, not what I have in the #modify input box.

Comment: afaik JS being async it will prepare the data before you modify anything in the #main so to export correctly you will need to update the contents exported in the moment you execute the modification, so update your a.href in the keyup function.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Rômulo Gabriel Rodrigues worked for me...

*"JS being async it will prepare the data before you modify anything in the #main so to export correctly you will need to update the contents exported in the moment you execute the modification, so update your a.href in the keyup function."*